# i have a proplem with django python

Tags: python, django

```
comments = project.masarif.filter(active=True)
def sub_masarif():
    for sub in comments:
        total = 0
        xdd = sub.count
        total += (xdd)
        print(total) # 3 4 69
```

i need sum `total` < example  `print(total) # 76`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You each time reset `total`, hence it each time prints the current value. You should set the `total = 0` variable *outside* the loop, so:

```
def sub_masarif():
    total = 0
    for sub in project.masarif.filter(active=True):
        xdd = sub.count
        total += sub.count
    print(total)
```

But you here aggregate at the Django/Python layer. Normally it is better to do this at the database side, so:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

def sub_masarif():
    total = project.masarif.filter(active=True).aggregate(total=Sum('count'))['total']
    print(total)
```